# Angular 2 Final + Webpack Beta.25 + AOT = Error

Tags: angular, typescript, runtime-error

my Angular App is throwing the following Runtime Error with Ahead of Time Compiling: 
    vendor.74a904a….bundle.js:15 EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

I dont know where i should start searching... if you need the source code to help me just visit https://rc-setup.de the sourcecode is attached to it (chrome: sources -> webpack:// and then there is the source)

Hope you can help me with this weird error!

-Andre

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Opened https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12287

Answer (score 1):

Currently AoT has a bug: it doesn't properly handle ViewEncapsulation.None. After removing this encapsulation strategy and moving some styles to global styles.css that problem was solved in our app.

Comment: I'm about to do the same to get my AoT builds working. I can see the bug in AoT but I'm not seeing an issue ticket for it on Github. Did you ever find a known issue ticket so we can know this is being fixed?